# Why declaring a variable inside a loop does not mean re declaring the variable each time loop is entered

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{
    int x;
    int x;
    return 0;
}
```

This snippet will give an error:

> error: redeclaration of 'int x'

But this one, works just fine:

```
int main()
{
    while(true)
    {
        int x;

        {...}
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Which is the reason why in the second example, declaring x in the loop does not redeclare it every iteration? I was expecting the same error as in the first case.

Comment: Try `int main(){{int x;}{int x;}}`.

Comment: Read about scopes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're smashing together two related but different concepts and thus your confusion. But it's not your fault, as most of the didactic material on the matter doesn't necessarily make the distinction between the two concepts clear.

1. **Variable scope**: This is the region of the source code where a symbol (a variable) is visible.
2. **Object lifetime**: this is the time during the runtime of the program that an object exists.

This brings us to other two concepts we need to understand and differentiate between:

1. **A variable** is a compile-time concept: it is a name (a symbol) that refers to objects
2. **An object** is an "entity" at runtime, an instance of a type.

Let's go back to your examples:

```
int main()
{
    int x{};
    int x{};
}
```

Here you try to declare 2 different variables inside the same scope. Those two variables would have the same name inside the function scope, so when you would "say" the name `x` (when you would write the symbol `x`) you wouldn't know to which variable you would refer. So it is not allowed.

```
int main()
{
    while(true)
    {
        int x{};
    }
}
```

Here you declare one variable inside the while body scope. When you write `x` inside this scope you refer to this variable. No ambiguity. No problems. Valid code. Note this discussion about declarations and variable scope applies at compile-time, i.e. we are discussion about what meaning has the code that you write.

When we discus object lifetime however we are talking about runtime, i.e. the moment when your compiled binary runs. Yes, at runtime, multiple objects will be created and destroyed in succession. All of these objects are referred by the symbol `x` inside the while body-scope. But the lifetimes of these objects **don't overlap**. I.e. when you run your program the first object is created. In the source code it is named `x` inside the while-body scope. Then the object is destroyed, the loop is re-entered and a new object is created. It is also named `x` in the source code inside the while-body scope. Then it is destroyed, the while is re-entered, a new object is created and so on.

---

To give you an expanded view on the matter, consider you can have:

#### A variable which never refers to an object

```
{ // not global scope
    int a; // <-- not initialized
}
```

The variable `a` is not initialized, so an object will never be created at runtime.

#### An object without a name:

```
int get_int();

{
    int sum = get_int() + get_int();
}
```

There are two objects returned by the two calls to the function `get_int()`. Those objects are temporaries. They are never named.

#### Multiple objects instantiated inside the scope of a variable.

This is an advanced, contrived example, at the fringe of C++. Just showing that it is technically possible:

```
{

    int x;

    // no object

    new (&x) int{11};  // <-- 1st object created. It is is named `x`. Start of its lifetime

    // 1st object is alive. Named x

    x.~int(); // <-- 1st object destructed. End of its lifetime

    // no object

    new (&x) int{24};  // <-- 2nd object created. Also named `x`

    // 2nd object alive. Named x

} // <-- implicit end of the lifetime of 2nd object.
```

The scope of `x` is the whole block delimited by the curly brackets. However there are two object with different non-overlapping lifetimes inside this scope.

Answer (score 2):

Declarations don't happen at runtime, they happen at compile-time.

In your code `int x;` is declared once, because it appears in the code once. It doesn't matter if it's in a loop or not.

---

If the loop runs more than once, `x` will be *created* and then destroyed more than once. It's allowed, of course.

Answer (score 1):

In c++, the curly braces represent the beginning `{`,  and end `}`, of a scope. If you have a scope nested inside another scope, for example a `while` loop inside a function, then the previously declared variables from the outer scope are available inside the new loop scope.

You are not allowed to declare a variable with the **same name** inside the **same scope** twice. That's why the compiler creates the first error

> error: redeclaration of 'int x'

But in the case of the loop, the variable is only declared once. It doesn't matter that the loop will reuse that declaration multiple times. Just like a function being called multiple times doesn't create a `redeclaration` error for the variables it declares.

Answer (score 0):

Variables in loops stay in loops, and are not redeclared. This is because, to the best of my knowledge, Loops are just sets of instructions with jump points, and not actually the same code in the .exe file written over and over again.

If you try to make a for loop:

```
 for(int x = 0; x < 10000; ++x);
```

The loop just reuses the same variable, then removes the variable after use. This is helpful so that loops, and do{}while(condition)'s can actally hold values, and not just have to redeclare, and reset each variable.

Back to the original question, I am going to ask my own: Why are you trying to redeclare a variable? You could just do this:

```
 int main(void){
 int variable = 0;
 ...
 variable = 2;
 }
```

Instead of this:

```
 int main(void){
 int variable = 0;
 ...
 int variable = 2;
 }
```

Comment: "_Loops are just sets of instructions with jump points, and not actually the same code in the .exe file written over and over again._" At the end of the day: the underlying implementation doesn't matter. .exe is not the only extension, of the file, that the code can be compiled into. There's .o, .so, .dll, .lib, and many others. What determines the rules of the language is C++ standard. So the answer would need to take it into account, instead of one possible implementation (if one possible implementation is dominant, it doesn't mean it's the only possible implementation: see Loop unrolling).

Comment: Ahhh. Thank you for correcting me on that one. I must now assume that the assembly initializes the variables outside the jump points.

Comment: "_I must now assume that the assembly initializes the variables outside the jump points._" You missed the entire point of my comment. When talking about C++ - you don't need to think about assembly. The assembly generation is just an implementation detail, and every implementation of compiler, can do it differently. What describes the rules, and behavior, of the language is C++ standard. Hence, you only need to think it terms outlined in it.

Answer (score 0):

Curly brackets in C/C++ represent blocks of code. These blocks of code do not transfer information to other blocks. I recommend looking further into resources on blocks of code, but one resource has been linked [here](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/41-blocks-compound-statements/).

Unlike code that is written in "interpreted languages", variables require declaration. Moreover, your code is read sequentially in compiled languages.

Block example:

```
while (true) {
   int i = 0;
}
```

This declaration is stored with the block somewhere in memory.
The storage is assigned to an "int" variable type. This data member has a certain memory capacity. Redeclaring, in essence, tries to override information stored in that particular block. These blocks are set aside at compilation time.