# Local variables definition in relation to scope, C++

Tags: c++, function, scope, function-call

When considering a local variable inside of main, e.g.

```
#include <iostream>
void doNothing(int x)
{
}

int main()
{
  int x{0}, y{0};
  doNothing(x);
  
  return 0;
}
```

Would both variables (x,y) still be considered in scope when the function doNothing() is entered? I understand that a variables scope extends to where the identifier can be accessed in source code, but from my understanding, y would be inaccessible inside of the function doNothing()

If it is to be understood that a local variables lifetimes starts when it enter scope and ends when it goes out of scope, would its lifetime then end and be reinstated when returning to main() during runtime?

I would suppose this is impossible as the variable would have to be redefined and reinstantiated which would mean returning to the top of main(), but then how is y still considered to still be in scope? Is the awaiting function call of doNothing(x) still holding it in scope?

(I understand this may seem to be a silly question as it clearly must somehow be in scope, I just like to have a clear definition of everything I am working with, perhaps overthinking it a bit too much)

This question comes from a note provided in a coding tutorial I am currently going through,

> Note that local variables have the same definitions for scope and lifetime. For local variables, scope and lifetime are linked -- that is, a variable’s lifetime starts when it enters scope, and ends when it goes out of scope.

Comment: scope and lifetime are different concepts. Scope deals with symbol names and lifetime is about objects.

Comment: Right, but it in the context of the quote I provided above being that local variables share the same definition of scope and lifetime even given that they are different concepts (compile-time vs. runtime), I am still confused as to whether or not its lifetime has ended or not. Perhaps the note I was provided in the tutorial is a bit confusing in its wording?

Comment: I think I understand though, during runtime its lifetime exists in the boundaries of what its scope was at compile-time. Being that it is in scope within the main function, its lifetime will persist until the point in which it would have exited its scope, (end of main).

Comment: According to the standard. The lifetime of an object starts when storage for that object is obtained [6.6.3 P1] and the lifetime ends when the destructor is called (or the memory release) [6.6.3 P2]. For Automatic Variables (your x/y) These variables are created and destroyed as per 8.7 [6.6.5.3]. Variables with automatic storage duration are initialized each time their declaration-statement is executed. Variables with automatic storage duration declared in the block are destroyed on exit from the block [8.7 P2].

Comment: i.e. The lifetime of an automatic variable starts when the thread of execution executes the declaration statement and ends when the thread of execution exits the scope where it was declared thus causing the destructor to be called. Note: Calling a function does not exit the scope in this context as the destructor would not be called. OK. `int` does not have a constructor/destructor but the equivalent rule applies (the wording is just harder to explain for POD types).

Comment: I highly appreciate all your help. I apologize many of my questions now and in the future may come across as being silly and probably not worth responding to, so I again appreciate all the help I receive when it comes to my various programming questions. You have all been very kind, thank you!

Comment: you need to stop thinking of one in terms of the other. Related, helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58924325/2805305

Comment: `but from my understanding, y would be inaccessible inside of the function doNothing()` indicates that you think that the `x` of  `int x{0}, y{0};` is accessible in `doNothing`, but this isn't either. The `x` is of `void doNothing(int x)` is a completely different variable.

Comment: I went under the assumption that x is still accessible in a sense of speaking as it becomes the parameter in the function. It is of course not directly accessible, but being it is used as the argument for the function call it is being accessed in some sense, so I just stuck with y in my question as to not add any further confusion into what I was trying to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope refers to the 'visibility' of a variable, so the scope of variables `x` and `y` is limited to `main()`.

> y would be inaccessible inside of the function doNothing()

Exactly!

> If it is to be understood that a local variables lifetimes starts when it enter scope and ends when it goes out of scope, would its lifetime then end and be reinstated when returning to main() during runtime?

Not quite. It sounds like you are asking about how long the variables exist in memory, which is usually what lifetime refers to. Locals like `x` and `y` are put into memory when `main()` starts but are deallocated when `main()` ends.

This page may be [helpful](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/%7Echeung/Courses/561/Syllabus/3-C/scoping.html) to understand scoping and lifetime.
Some takeaways:

> - A variable begins to exist when the variable is defined
> - A variable stops to exist at the end of the scope in which the variable is defined

Hope this is helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

> Would both variables (x,y) still be considered in scope **when** the function doNothing()

The problem in your question is that scope has no notion of time. It only has a notion of place.

Symbols do not go in and out of scope as the program is executed. A Symbols is either in scope or out of scope at a given location within the program.